C++20 Performance Test Code Generator
My previous question about a generic dictionary class for C++ raised some valid concerns. I have made some modifications based on the previous review, but it needs extensive testing and further modifications before it is ready to be reviewed again.
The previous testing did not attempt to do any performance testing, the program here is a performance test generator. It is written in C++20 and generates C++20 code.
The performance test generator can generate up to ten cases, each test case can be over 1M enums. The code it generates compiles and runs.
Test cases of 4K enums generates about 17K lines of code. These compile and run. The 17K lines takes almost exactly 2 minutes to compile. Run time is under 1 second.
Development Environment

Lenovo P50

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
4 core 8 thread
Memory 32557MB (3320MB used)
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, all patches current


C++20
gcc-12 compiler
CMake

Test Output from 4K enum:
Testing GenericDictionary with enum of size 4096
>>>> Finished Performance Test Constructor performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 0.0407159


>>>> Finished Performance Test find string from [4095] ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 7.8807e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find string from [3071] ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 5.8774e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find string from [2047] ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 3.9203e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find string from [1023] ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 2.0157e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find string from [0] ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 8.85e-07


>>>> Finished Performance Test find ID from [4095] Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 0.000113114


>>>> Finished Performance Test find ID from [3071] Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 8.0604e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find ID from [2047] Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 4.7772e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find ID from [1023] Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 1.5479e-05


>>>> Finished Performance Test find ID from [0] Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 9.4e-07


>>>> Finished Performance Loop Test find string from ID performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 0.159599


>>>> Finished Performance Loop Test find ID from Name performanceTest4096 Wed Oct  2 16:00:03 2024
>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: 0.15896


GenericDictionary Constructor performanceTest4096 PASSED

Code to Review
The code I most want reviewed is main.cpp and BasicGenericDictionaryTests.h, but you are free to review all or any part of the code.
The GitHub repository. You will need the parent directory if you want to build the test code and run it.
main.cpp (Performance test generator code).
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "../UtilityTimer.h"

static std::size_t MinEnumVal = 1;
static std::string enumTemplate("GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_");
static std::string enumName("GDPerformanceTestEnum");
static std::string testStrTemplate("Performance Test String ");
static std::string testStrVectorName("GDPerformanceTestStrings");

static void generateEnum(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "typedef enum class " << enumName << testSize << "\n";
    testOut << "{\n\tGD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,\n";
    for (std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal; lcount <= testSize; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << "\t" << enumTemplate << lcount << ",\n";
    }
    testOut << "\tGD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM\n} " << enumName << testSize << ";\n";
}

static void generateStringVector(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "static std::vector<std::string> " << testStrVectorName << testSize << " = \n{\n"
        "\t\"\", // For GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE\n";
    for (std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal; lcount <= testSize; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << "\t\"" << testStrTemplate << lcount << "\",\n";
    }
    testOut << "\t\"\" // For GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM\n};\n";
}

static std::string genEnumPreVal(std::size_t testSize)
{
    std::string tSize(std::to_string(testSize));
    std::string preEnumValue(enumName);
    return (preEnumValue += tSize);
}

static void genTestDataPairs(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize, std::size_t tabCount = 1)
{
    std::string tSize(std::to_string(testSize));
    std::string enumValue(genEnumPreVal(testSize));
    enumValue += "::" + enumTemplate;
    std::string strValue(testStrVectorName);
    strValue += tSize + "[";
    std::string tabPlusOpen;
    for (std::size_t tcount = 0; tcount < tabCount; ++tcount)
    {
        tabPlusOpen += "\t";
    }
    tabPlusOpen += "{";

    std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal;
    for (; lcount < testSize ; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << tabPlusOpen << enumValue << lcount << ", " << strValue <<
            lcount << "]},\n";
    }
    testOut << tabPlusOpen << enumValue << lcount << ", " << strValue <<
            lcount << "]}\n";
}

static void genTestDataStructVector(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    std::string tpVecName("testData");
    tpVecName += std::to_string(testSize);

    testOut << "\nstatic std::vector<struct TestPairs<" << genEnumPreVal(testSize) <<
        ">> " << tpVecName << " =\n{\n";
    genTestDataPairs(testOut, testSize);
    testOut << "};\n\n";
}

static std::string genTestFunc(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    std::string enumBase(genEnumPreVal(testSize));
    std::string testName("performanceTest");
    testName += std::to_string(testSize);

    testOut << "static bool " << testName << "()\n{\n" <<
        "\tbool testPassed = true;\n\tUtilityTimer testTimer;\n\n\tstd::string testName(\"" <<
        testName <<"\");\n\n\ttry {\n" <<
        "\t\tstd::clog << \"Testing GenericDictionary with enum of size " << testSize << "\\n\";" <<
        "\n\t\ttestTimer.startTimer();" <<
        "\n\t\tGenericDictionary <" << enumBase  << ", std::string> underTest (\n";
    enumBase += "::";
    testOut << "\t\t\t" << enumBase << "GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,\n"
        "\t\t\t" << enumBase << "GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM,\n\t\t\t{\n";
    genTestDataPairs(testOut, testSize, 4);
    testOut << "\t\t\t}\n\t\t);\n\t\ttestTimer.stopTimerAndReport(\"Performance Test Constructor \" + testName + \" \");\n\n\t\t" <<
        "testPassed = performanceExecution<" << genEnumPreVal(testSize) <<
        ">(underTest, testData" << testSize << ", testName);\n"
        "\n\t}\n"
        "\tcatch (const std::logic_error &le)\n\t{\n"
        "\t\tstd::cerr << \"TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() logic_error: \" << le.what() << \"\\n\\n\";\n"
        "\t\ttestPassed = false;\n\t}\n"
        "\tcatch(const std::exception& e)\n\t{\n"
        "\t\tstd::cerr << \"TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() UNKNOWN EXCEPTION: \" << e.what() << \"\\n\";\n"        
        "\t\ttestPassed = false;\n\t}\n";
    testOut << "\tstd::clog << \"GenericDictionary Constructor " << testName <<
        " \" << (testPassed? \"PASSED\\n\\n\": \"FAILED\\n\\n\");\n\n"
        "\treturn testPassed;\n}\n\n";

    return testName;
}


static std::string generateAllTestDataAndTest(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "// Generated GenericDictionary Performance Test Values for an enum class of ";
    testOut << testSize << " enum values\n\n";

    generateEnum(testOut, testSize);

    testOut << "\n";
    generateStringVector(testOut, testSize);

    testOut << "\n";
    genTestDataStructVector(testOut, testSize);

    testOut << "\n";
    return genTestFunc(testOut, testSize);
}

static void genPerformanceTest(std::ofstream &testOut, std::vector<std::size_t> testValues)
{
    std::vector<std::string> testNames;
    for (auto test: testValues)
    {
        testNames.push_back(generateAllTestDataAndTest(testOut, test));
    }

    testOut << "bool performancetests()\n{\n\tbool allTestsPassed = true;\n\n";
    for (auto test: testNames)
    {
        testOut << "\tif (allTestsPassed)\n\t{\n\t\tallTestsPassed = " << test << "();\n\t}\n";
    }
    testOut << "\n\treturn allTestsPassed;\n}\n\n";
}

static bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), 
        s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

static std::size_t safeUserNumericInput(std::string message, std::size_t minValue, std::size_t maxValue)
{
    std::size_t safeNumber;

    std::string safeInput;
    bool hasNumber = false;

    do {
        std::cout << message << " [" << minValue << "," << maxValue << "]\n>>";
        std::cin >> safeInput;
        hasNumber = is_number(safeInput);
        if (hasNumber)
        {
            safeNumber = std::stoi(safeInput);
            hasNumber = (safeNumber >= minValue || safeNumber <= maxValue);
        }
    } while (!hasNumber);

    return safeNumber;
}

static std::vector<std::size_t> getUserInput()
{
    const std::size_t MIN_TEST_COUNT = 1;
    const std::size_t MAX_TEST_COUNT = 10;
    const std::size_t MIN_TEST_VALUE = 1;
    const std::size_t MAX_TEST_VALUE = (1024 * 1024 * 3);

    std::vector<std::size_t> testValues;

    std::size_t testCount = 
        safeUserNumericInput("Enter the number of tests to generate", MIN_TEST_COUNT, MAX_TEST_COUNT);
    for (std::size_t lcount = 0; lcount < testCount; ++lcount)
    {
        testValues.push_back(
            safeUserNumericInput("Enter the number of enums to generate for this test", MIN_TEST_VALUE, MAX_TEST_VALUE)
        );
    }

    return testValues;
}

int main(void)
{
    int exitStatus = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    std::ofstream testOut;
    testOut.open("performanceTest.h");

    std::vector<std::size_t> testValues = getUserInput();

    testOut << "#ifndef GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_\n";
    testOut << "#define GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_\n\n";
    testOut << "// Warning, this file is generated by a test generator\n";
    testOut << "// This file contains " << testValues.size() << " performance tests\n";
    testOut << "// ";
    for (auto testEnumCount: testValues)
    {
        testOut << " test " << testEnumCount << "enum values";
    }
    testOut << "\n\n";
    testOut << "#include \"../../include/GenericDictionary.h\"\n";
    testOut << "#include \"../BasicGenericDictionaryTests.h\"\n";
    testOut << "#include <string>\n";
    testOut << "#include \"../UtilityTimer.h\"\n";
    testOut << "#include <vector>\n\n\n";
    genPerformanceTest(testOut, testValues);
    testOut << "#endif // GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_\n\n";

    testOut.close();

    return exitStatus;
}

CMake file to create the performance test header file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(createPerformanceTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(createPerformanceTest main.cpp)

target_compile_features(createPerformanceTest PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    # warning level 4 and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(createPerformanceTest PRIVATE /W4 /WX -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
        # require at least gcc 12 to get full C++20 support
        if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 12)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "GCC version must be at least 12!")
        endif()
    endif()
    # lots of warnings and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(createPerformanceTest PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
endif()

Performance test main.cpp source code, not generated.
#include "../PerformanceTestGenerator/performanceTest.h"

int main(void)
{
    if (!performancetests())
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Header files included by the generated performanceTest.h file
BasicGenericDictionaryTests.h
#ifndef BASICGENERICDICTIONARYTESTS_H_
#define BASICGENERICDICTIONARYTESTS_H_

#include "../include/GenericDictionary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "UtilityTimer.h"

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testIdToName(
    GenericDictionary<enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    enumDictType testID,
    std::string expectedOutput,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    std::string testGetName = underTest.getNames(testID);
    if (testGetName.compare(expectedOutput) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr
            << "\t" << errorMessage << " Input Value " <<
            static_cast<std::size_t>(testID)
            << " Expected Output " << expectedOutput << " " 
            << " Actual Ouput " << testGetName << "\n";
            ;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testNameToID(
    GenericDictionary<enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    std::string testName,
    enumDictType expectedOutput,
    std::string errorMessage
    )
{
    enumDictType testGetID = underTest.getIds(testName);
    if (testGetID != expectedOutput)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "\t " << errorMessage << " get ID from Name FAILED: "
            << "Input Name: " << testName
            << " Expected Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(expectedOutput)
            << " Actual Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(testGetID)
            << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename  enumDictType>
struct TestPairs
{
    enumDictType testID;
    std::string testName;
};

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testIDtoNameLoop(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    std::vector<struct TestPairs<enumDictType>> &TestData,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    for (auto test: TestData)
    {
        enumDictType testId = test.testID;
        std::string expectedOutPut = test.testName;
        std::string testGetName = underTest.getNames(testId);
        if (testGetName.compare(expectedOutPut) != 0)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "\t" << errorMessage << " Input Value " <<
                static_cast<std::size_t>(testId)
                << " Expected Output " << expectedOutPut << " " 
                << " Actual Ouput " << testGetName << "\n";
                ;
            allTestsPassed = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testNametoIDLoop(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    std::vector<struct TestPairs<enumDictType>> &TestData,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    for (auto test: TestData)
    {
        std::string testName = TestData.testName;
        enumDictType expectedOutput = TestData.testId;
        enumDictType testGetID = underTest.getIds(testName);
        if (testGetID != expectedOutput)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                "\t " << errorMessage << " get ID from Name FAILED: "
                << "Input Name: " << testName
                << " Expected Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(expectedOutput)
                << " Actual Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(testGetID)
                << "\n";
            allTestsPassed = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testMinMaxMiddleValues(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    std::vector<struct TestPairs<enumDictType>> &testData,
    std::string testName
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes;
    indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>(testData.size() - 1));
    if (testData.size() > 10)
    {
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.75) - 1));
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.5) - 1));
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.25) -1));
    }
    indexes.push_back(0);

    for (auto tIndex: indexes)
    {
        auto tDp = testData[tIndex];
        std::string testReport = "Performance Test find string from [" + std::to_string(tIndex) + "] ID " + testName + " ";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        allTestsPassed = testIdToName<enumDictType>(underTest, tDp.testID, tDp.testName, testName + " testIDToName()");
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport(testReport);
        if (!allTestsPassed)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (auto tIndex: indexes)
    {
        auto tDp = testData[tIndex];
        std::string testReport = "Performance Test find ID from [" + std::to_string(tIndex) + "] Name " + testName + " ";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        allTestsPassed = testNameToID<enumDictType>(underTest, tDp.testName, tDp.testID, testName + " testNameToID()");
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport(testReport);
        if (!allTestsPassed)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool performanceExecution(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string> &underTest,
    std::vector<struct TestPairs<enumDictType>> &testData,
    std::string testName
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    testMinMaxMiddleValues<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName);
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    testTimer.startTimer();
    testIDtoNameLoop<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName + " testIDtoNameLoop()");
    testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Loop Test find string from ID " + testName + " ");
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    testTimer.startTimer();
    testIDtoNameLoop<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName + " testIDtoNameLoop()");
    testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Loop Test find ID from Name " + testName + " ");
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

#endif // BASICGENERICDICTIONARYTESTS_H_


UtilityTimer.h
Note: This is a slightly modified version of UtilityTimer.h that was first introduced in Portable Object-Oriented WC (Linux Utility word Count) C++ 20, Counts Lines, Words Bytes.
#ifndef CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H
#define CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H

/*
 * Chernick Consulting Utility timer class.
 * Encapsulates execution timing for all or parts of a program.
 */

#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

class UtilityTimer
{
public:
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    void startTimer() noexcept
    {
        start = clock::now();
    }
    void stopTimerAndReport(std::string_view whatIsBeingTimed) noexcept
    {
        clock::time_point end = clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        double ElapsedTimeForOutPut = elapsed_seconds.count();

        using std::chrono::system_clock;
        auto const now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
        std::clog << ">>>> Finished " << whatIsBeingTimed << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%c")
              << "\n>>>> Elapsed time in seconds: " << ElapsedTimeForOutPut << "\n\n\n";
    }

private:
    clock::time_point start = clock::now();
};

#endif // CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H


Minimal generated performance test code example performanceTest.h
#ifndef GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_
#define GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_

// Warning, this file is generated by a test generator
// This file contains 1 performance tests
//  test 16enum values

#include "../../include/GenericDictionary.h"
#include "../BasicGenericDictionaryTests.h"
#include <string>
#include "../UtilityTimer.h"
#include <vector>


// Generated GenericDictionary Performance Test Values for an enum class of 16 enum values

typedef enum class GDPerformanceTestEnum16
{
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_1,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_2,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_3,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_4,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_5,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_6,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_7,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_8,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_9,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_10,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_11,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_12,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_13,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_14,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_15,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_16,
    GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM
} GDPerformanceTestEnum16;

static std::vector<std::string> GDPerformanceTestStrings16 = 
{
    "", // For GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE
    "Performance Test String 1",
    "Performance Test String 2",
    "Performance Test String 3",
    "Performance Test String 4",
    "Performance Test String 5",
    "Performance Test String 6",
    "Performance Test String 7",
    "Performance Test String 8",
    "Performance Test String 9",
    "Performance Test String 10",
    "Performance Test String 11",
    "Performance Test String 12",
    "Performance Test String 13",
    "Performance Test String 14",
    "Performance Test String 15",
    "Performance Test String 16",
    "" // For GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM
};


static std::vector<struct TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>> testData16 =
{
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_1, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[1]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_2, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[2]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_3, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[3]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_4, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[4]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_5, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[5]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_6, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[6]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_7, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[7]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_8, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[8]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_9, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[9]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_10, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[10]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_11, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[11]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_12, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[12]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_13, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[13]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_14, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[14]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_15, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[15]},
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_16, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[16]}
};


static bool performanceTest16()
{
    bool testPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    std::string testName("performanceTest16");

    try {
        std::clog << "Testing GenericDictionary with enum of size 16\n";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        GenericDictionary <GDPerformanceTestEnum16, std::string> underTest (
            GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,
            GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM,
            {
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_1, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[1]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_2, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[2]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_3, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[3]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_4, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[4]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_5, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[5]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_6, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[6]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_7, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[7]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_8, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[8]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_9, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[9]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_10, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[10]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_11, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[11]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_12, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[12]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_13, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[13]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_14, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[14]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_15, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[15]},
                {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_16, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[16]}
            }
        );
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Test Constructor " + testName + " ");

        testPassed = performanceExecution<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>(underTest, testData16, testName);

    }
    catch (const std::logic_error &le)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() logic_error: " << le.what() << "\n\n";
        testPassed = false;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() UNKNOWN EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << "\n";
        testPassed = false;
    }
    std::clog << "GenericDictionary Constructor performanceTest16 " << (testPassed? "PASSED\n\n": "FAILED\n\n");

    return testPassed;
}

bool performancetests()
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    if (allTestsPassed)
    {
        allTestsPassed = performanceTest16();
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

#endif // GD_PERFORMANCETEST_H_


GenericDictionary.h
This is the code being tested. It is not ready for another review yet, there may be major changes based on the testing.
#ifndef GENERICDICTIONARY_H_
#define GENERICDICTIONARY_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/*
 * This class provides defIter1 basic conversion of enums or integers to strings. The
 * class can be used as is, or as defIter1 base for defIter1 more complex object.
 * 
 * More complex objects than strings are also supported, however, overrides will
 * be necessary.
 * 
 * This class makes an attempt to find any missing definitions during construction.
 * 
 * Enums or integers should have an illegal value as 0. If not, then override the
 * getIds method.
 * 
 * The code has been modified based on defIter1 Code Review
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293782/generic-c-class-to-associate-enum-values-with-strings-for-translation
 * Changes since the review
 * - A constructor and destructor have been added.
 * - The constructor checks for missing definitions
 * - The class is no longer abstract
 * - dicID became dictID and dicName became dictName
 * 
 */
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
class GenericDictionary
{
public:
    struct DictType
    {
        dictID id;
        dictName names;
    };

// Both the MinValue and MaxValue should be invalid values
// Example
// GenericDictionary(enum::NO_VALUE, enum::LAST_VALUE)
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)
    : MinimumValue{MinValue},
    MaximumValue{MaxValue},
    searchTable{definitions}
    {
        constructorMissingIDSizeTest();
        
        // To improve performance when searhing by id sort by id.
        // This sort is only necessary if the underlying structure remains
        // defIter1 vector. If it is std::map() the sort is not necessary.
        std::sort(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
            [](DictType defIter1, DictType defIter2) {return  defIter1.id < defIter2.id;});

        // Check for any missing or duplicate definitions now that the data is sorted.
        testForNoneLinearDefinitions();
    }

    virtual ~GenericDictionary() = default;

    virtual dictID getIds(dictName itemName) noexcept
    {
        auto definition = std::find_if(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
            [&itemName](struct DictType &dicItem) {return (dicItem.names == itemName);});

        if (definition != searchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->id;
        }

        return static_cast<dictID>(MinimumValue);
    };

    virtual dictName getNames(dictID id) noexcept
    {
        if (MinimumValue > id || id < MaximumValue)
        {
            auto definition = std::ranges::find(searchTable, id, &DictType::id);
            if (definition != searchTable.end())
            {
                return definition->names;
            }
        }

        dictName nameNotFound;
        return nameNotFound;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool addDefinition(dictID id, dictName name) noexcept
    {
        DictType newDef(id, name);
        if (!alreadyDefined(newDef))
        {
            searchTable.push_back(newDef);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

protected:
/*
 * If the enum was constructed correctly, there are 2 enums defined that do not
 * have associated strings, the first enum, that has defIter1 zero value and the last
 * enum that can be used to calculate the number of enums.
 */
    void constructorMissingIDSizeTest()
    {
        std::size_t expectedSize = static_cast<std::size_t>(MaximumValue);
        expectedSize -= 1;
        if (searchTable.size() != expectedSize)
        {
            std::logic_error missingDefinitions("In GenericDictionary Constructor missing definion values");
                throw missingDefinitions;
        }
    }

    bool hasID(dictID id) noexcept
    {
        std::size_t countID = std::ranges::count(searchTable, id, &DictType::id);
        return (countID > 0);
    }

    bool hasName(dictName name) noexcept
    {
        std::size_t countID = std::ranges::count(searchTable, name, &DictType::names);
        return (countID > 0);
    }

    bool alreadyDefined(DictType candidate) noexcept
    {
        return hasID(candidate.id) || hasName(candidate.names);
    }

    bool hasDuplicateIds()
    {
        for (auto defintion: searchTable)
        {
            std::size_t countID = std::ranges::count(searchTable, defintion->id, &DictType::id);
            if (countID > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool hasDuplicateNames()
    {
        for (auto defintion: searchTable)
        {
            std::size_t countNames = std::ranges::count(searchTable, defintion->names, &DictType::names);
            if (countNames > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Assumption, the input for this function has been sorted by ID.
     */
    void testForNoneLinearDefinitions()
    {
        for (auto defIter2 = searchTable.begin() + 1; defIter2 < searchTable.end(); defIter2++ )
        {
            auto defIter1 = defIter2 - 1;
            std::size_t id1 = static_cast<std::size_t>(defIter1->id);
            std::size_t id2 = static_cast<std::size_t>(defIter2->id);
            if (id1 != (id2 - 1))
            {
                std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary Constructor: ");
                emsg += (id1 == id2)? "duplicate definition values: " : 
                    "missing definition value: ";
                emsg += std::to_string((id2 - 1));

                std::logic_error orderError(emsg);
                throw orderError;
            }
        }
    }

    dictID MinimumValue;
    dictID MaximumValue;
    // This is currently implemented using std::vector to
    // the avoid multiple allocations on the heap using
    // std::map
    std::vector<DictType> searchTable;
};

#endif // GENERICDICTIONARY_H_


static std::size_t MinEnumVal = 1;
static std::string enumTemplate("GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_");
static std::string enumName("GDPerformanceTestEnum");
static std::string testStrTemplate("Performance Test String ");
static std::string testStrVectorName("GDPerformanceTestStrings");

There’s no reason these can’t all be compile time constants. In the case of the strings, you would have to make them string views instead, but that won’t have any impact on their usage in the code:
constexpr auto MinEnumVal = 1uz;
constexpr auto enumTemplate = "GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_VALUE_"sv;

… and so on.
static void generateEnum(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)

There is no real benefit to taking a ofstream reference over a ostream reference. I don’t know if you were hoping for devirtualization, but compared to the costs of formatting and writing to files, any gains from that will be meaningless. And the cost is that you can’t write to any other stream type… like, for example, std::cout. Or, even more importantly, std::ostringstream, which would make testing this function much, much easier. (And you should be testing this function, and all other functions.)
Also, as a style point, in C++ we prefer to keep the type modifiers with the type. In other words:

std::ofstream &testOut: this is C style
std::ofstream& testOut: this is C++ style

static void generateEnum(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "typedef enum class " << enumName << testSize << "\n";
    testOut << "{\n\tGD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,\n";
    for (std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal; lcount <= testSize; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << "\t" << enumTemplate << lcount << ",\n";
    }
    testOut << "\tGD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM\n} " << enumName << testSize << ";\n";
}

So, a couple of things about the code you’re generating. I don’t see why you want:
typedef enum class foo
{
    //...
} foo;

… rather than just:
enum class foo
{
    // ...
};

It’s not just that the older typedef syntax is being used over the more modern using syntax, it’s that the alias itself is completely superfluous. If you’re lucky, the user’s compiler won’t complain about it… but it might, and if the user has warnings-as-errors turned on… that will kill the compile, for a completely silly reason.
Also, using SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for non-macros is unwise.
Now, a warning about a potential bug: You assume that MinEnumVal is 1… which it is, because that’s how you set it. But is it intended to be customizable? I can’t tell if it’s been pulled out as a constant just to give it a name (which would be good and fine), or because it is intended to allow for the value to be changed to something other than 1. A comment to explain such a high-level assumption would help.
Even if the intention is not to allow MinEnumVal to be anythong other than 1, it still makes sense to code defensively. And if MinEnumVal is not 1, then this loop:
    for (std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal; lcount <= testSize; ++lcount)

… will not execute testSize times. Which could be problematic.
A quick-and-dirty fix would be:
    for (auto lcount = 0uz; lcount != testSize; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << "\t" << enumTemplate << (lcount + MinEnumVal) << ",\n";
    }

… which is probably what you meant this code to mean.
But using a raw for loop is an anti-pattern in any case. So you probably want something more like:
static void generateEnum(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "typedef enum class " << enumName << testSize << "\n";
    testOut << "{\n\tGD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE,\n";

    for_each(
        std::views::iota(0, testSize)
            | std::views::transform([] (auto i) { return i + MinEnumVal; }),
        [&testOut] (auto i) { testOut << "\t" << enumTemplate << i << ",\n"; }
    );

    testOut << "\tGD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM\n} " << enumName << testSize << ";\n";
}

… or:
auto generateEnum(std::ostream& out, std::size_t size)
{
    std::println(out, "enum class {}{}\n{{\n\tinvalid_value,", enumName, size);

    for (auto i : std::views::iota(0, size) | std::views::transform([] (auto i) { return i + MinEnumVal; }))
        std::println(out, "\t{}{},", enumTemplate, i);

    std::println(out, "\tlast_enum\n}};");
}

… or whatever.
However, I would suggest that this function, small as it is, does too much. It is a high-level function to generate a specific enumeration. It should just do the high-level stuff, and then pass the actual enumeration generation on to a function that specifically just does enumeration generation, and nothing else. In other words, something more like:
template<std::ranges::input_range R>
auto generate_enumeration(std::string_view name, R&& enumerators, std::ostream& out)
{
    // Maybe validate the name and enumerators...

    std::println(out, "enum class {}\n{{", name);

    std::ranges::for_each(std::forward<R>(enumerators), [&out] (auto&& e) { std::println(out, "\t{},", e); });

    std::println(out, "}};");
}

auto generate_SPECIFIC_enumeration(std::size_t size, std::ostream& out)
{
    // Maybe validate that size + MinEnumVal doesn't overflow...

    return generate_enumeration(enumName,
        std::views::iota(0 + MinEnumVal, size + MinEnumVal)
            | std::views::transform([] (auto i) { return std::format("{}{}", enumTemplate, i); }),
        out
    );
}

Each function has a single, clear-cut responsibility, and can be tested up the wazoo. Business logic is separated from low-level nuts-and-bolts logic, so you can change the nature of the generated enumeration without touching the code that generates enumerations… meaning you can always be sure you are generating a valid enumeration, no matter how you tinker with the business logic.
And, of course, you can always take out the code generation stuff and make it its own library, so it can be reused. (You could also massively expand it, so you could generate enumerations with enumerator values, and maybe even attributes, optional comments on each enumerator, and whatever else.)
Note that if you do it this way, and the constants MinEnumVal and enumName, assuming they are not meant to be configurable, could be localized into the business logic function. That makes sense, and it would be the most obvious place to look if you were trying to find them. (Put yourself in the shoes of someone who is looking at the generate code, and trying to debug some problem. A logical strategy would be to search for generated code identifiers. But if you search for GDPerformanceTestEnum in your existing code, you are not taken to anywhere useful… you are just taken to where the constant enumName is defined, completely isolated from where it is used, or anywhere it is relevant. Yes, sure, you can then take a second step and search for enumName and then find meaningful code. But it would be better if you could find relevant code in one shot rather than two.)
static void generateStringVector(std::ofstream &testOut, std::size_t testSize)
{
    testOut << "static std::vector<std::string> " << testStrVectorName << testSize << " = \n{\n"
        "\t\"\", // For GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST_INVALID_VALUE\n";
    for (std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal; lcount <= testSize; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << "\t\"" << testStrTemplate << lcount << "\",\n";
    }
    testOut << "\t\"\" // For GD_PERFORMANCE_LAST_ENUM\n};\n";
}

This function has the same problems as the previous one. The name is unrevealing, just describing the structure of the thing being generated… not what it actually is. Imagine if you saw a function named generateString(). The name is probably technically correct, but pretty uninformative. Imagine instead if it were called generateTestIdentifier(). Much more informative, non?
What this is actually generating is the string table for the enumeration. So generateEnumStringTable()?
It makes sense that generateEnumStringTable() could call a function named generateStringVector(). But it does more than just that, at least logically.
And, again, an actually string vector generation function could be so much better. It could, for example, make sure the strings are valid.
Now, as for the actual business logic, I don’t see why you define a string collection, and then a mapping of the strings to the enumeration values. Why the extra clutter? The strings themselves are meaningless; they serve no purpose outside of being mapped to the enumerators.
First… why a vector of strings? There doesn’t seem to be any intention for it to be altered, resized, or added to. Why not an array of strings? The string data has to be stored in static memory anyway, and then copied into the vector’s strings. Why not ditch the extra step, and just directly access the static memory?
And, in fact, why not an array of string views. Then there is no need for any data copying or allocation. The data is all in static memory, and you just directly read it when you need it.
So, as a first pass, you could generate:
enum class GDPerformanceTestEnum16
{
    invalid_value,
    value_1,
    // ...
    value_16,
    last_enum
};

constexpr auto GDPerformanceTestStrings16 = std::array<std::string_view, 18>
{
    "", // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::invalid_value
    "Performance Test String 1",
    // ...
    "Performance Test String 16",
    "" // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::last_enum
};

// OR:
//constexpr auto GDPerformanceTestStrings16 = std::to_array<std::string_view>({
//    "", // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::invalid_value
//    "Performance Test String 1",
//    // ...
//    "Performance Test String 16",
//    "" // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::last_enum
//});

// OR:
//constexpr auto GDPerformanceTestStrings16 = std::array{
//    std::string_view{}, // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::invalid_value
//    std::string_view{"Performance Test String 1"},
//    // ...
//    std::string_view{"Performance Test String 16"},
//    std::string_view{} // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::last_enum
//};

static std::vector<struct TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>> testData16 =
{
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_1, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[1]},
    // ...
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_16, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[16]}
};

Now, of course, we could do the same thing to the next vector:
enum class GDPerformanceTestEnum16
{
    invalid_value,
    value_1,
    // ...
    value_16,
    last_enum
};

constexpr auto GDPerformanceTestStrings16 = std::array<std::string_view, 18>
{
    "", // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::invalid_value
    "Performance Test String 1",
    // ...
    "Performance Test String 16",
    "" // For GDPerformanceTestEnum16::last_enum
};

constexpr auto testData16 = std::array<TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>, 18>
{
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_1, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[1]},
    // ...
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_16, GDPerformanceTestStrings16[16]}
};

And now we can ask… do we really need the intermediate table? Why not:
enum class GDPerformanceTestEnum16
{
    invalid_value,
    value_1,
    // ...
    value_16,
    last_enum
};

constexpr auto testData16 = std::array<TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>, 16>
{
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_1, "Performance Test String 1"},
    // ...
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_16, "Performance Test String 16"}
};

// OR:
//constexpr auto testData16 = std::array{
//    TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>{GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_1, "Performance Test String 1"},
//    // ...
//    TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>{GDPerformanceTestEnum16::value_16, "Performance Test String 16"}
//};

Note that you can probably simplify a lot by not encoding the size in everything. There doesn’t seem to be any good reason for naming the enumeration GDPerformanceTestEnum16 and not just GDPerformanceTestEnum, or naming the variable testData16 and not just testData.
In fact, currently the entire generated header file, roughly, has to be custom-generated each time. But consider instead if you just custom-generated the following:
constexpr auto enum_size = 16uz;

enum class GDPerformanceTestEnum
{
    invalid_value,
    value_1,
    // ...
    value_16,
    last_enum
};

constexpr auto testData = std::array<TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum>, enum_size>
{
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum::value_1, "Performance Test String 1"},
    // ...
    {GDPerformanceTestEnum::value_16, "Performance Test String 16"}
};

… and now, with a few small tweaks, everything else in the generated output can just be copied verbatim:
static bool performanceTest()
{
    bool testPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    // Use the enum_size constant instead of hard-coding it directly in the string:
    std::string testName("performanceTest" + std::to_string(enum_size));

    try {
        // Again, use enum_size constant:
        std::clog << "Testing GenericDictionary with enum of size " << enum_size "\n";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        GenericDictionary <GDPerformanceTestEnum, std::string> underTest (
            GDPerformanceTestEnum::invalid_value,
            GDPerformanceTestEnum::last_enum,
            // Use the test data array, instead of repeating its initializers:
            testData
        );
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Test Constructor " + testName + " ");

        testPassed = performanceExecution<GDPerformanceTestEnum>(underTest, testData, testName);

    }
    catch (const std::logic_error &le)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() logic_error: " << le.what() << "\n\n";
        testPassed = false;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() UNKNOWN EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << "\n";
        testPassed = false;
    }
    // Use enum_size instead of hard-coding in string:
    std::clog << "GenericDictionary Constructor performanceTest" << enum_size << " " << (testPassed? "PASSED\n\n": "FAILED\n\n");

    return testPassed;
}

bool performancetests()
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    if (allTestsPassed)
    {
        allTestsPassed = performanceTest();
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

Since something like 80–90% of your code generator is now just verbatim copying, that massively simplifies things, non?
In fact, I would suggest only generating the enumeration, the string mapping table, and the size constant. The rest could just be in the test main.cpp.
OR, if there must be multiple test enumerations and string maps, then perhaps a better idea would be to make a test type templated on the test number—which contains the enumeration and string map—and then have the test function use that. For example:
// Not generated: base test class.
template<std::size_t N>
struct test_t
{
    // Default implementation should just fail somehow:
    static_assert("not a valid test");
};

// Generated test 1:
template<>
struct test_t<1uz>
{
    enum class enum_t
    {
        value_1 = 1,
        value_2,
        // ...
    };

    struct pair_t
    {
        enum_t id;
        std::string_view name;
    };

    static constexpr auto invalid_value = static_cast<enum_t>(0);
    static constexpr auto last_enum = static_cast<enum_t>(0);

    static constexpr auto map = std::array{
        pair_t{enum_t::value_1, "string 1"},
        pair_t{enum_t::value_2, "string 2"},
        // ...
    };
};

// Generated test 2:
template<>
struct test_t<2uz>
{
    // Same idea as above.
};

// Not generated: test function.
template<std::size_t N>
auto performance_test()
{
    auto const test_name = "performanceTest" + std::to_string(N);

    auto passed = false; // so pessimistic!
    try
    {
        std::clog << "Testing GenericDictionary with enum of size " << N << "\n";

        auto timer = UtilityTimer{};
        timer.startTimer();

        auto underTest = GenericDictionary<test_t<N>::enum_t, std::string>(
            test_t<N>::invalid_value,
            test_t<N>::last_enum,
            test_t<N>::map
        );

        timer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Test Constructor " + test_name + " ");

        passed = performanceExecution<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>(underTest, testData16, test_name);
    }
    catch (std::logic_error const& x)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() logic_error: " << x.what() << "\n\n";
    }
    catch(std::exception const& x)
    {
        std::cerr << "TestGenericDictionary::testContructorPositivePath() UNKNOWN EXCEPTION: " << x.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::clog << "GenericDictionary Constructor performanceTest" << N << ' ' << (passed ? "PASSED\n\n": "FAILED\n\n");

    return passed;
}

// Not generated: function to run multiple tests.
template<std::size_t... N>
auto multiple_performance_tests()
{
    return (... and performance_test<N>);
}

// Generated: function to run all tests.
auto performance_tests()
{
    return multiple_performance_tests<1, 2 /* , ... */>();
}

Basically: just generate the structured test wrappers, and a function to run them all, and let everything else be copied verbatim (or included).
There is one extra tweak need to make all the above work, and that’s in GenericDictionary, but it’s really a change that should be made anyway.
Currently GenericDictionary has a single constructor:
template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::GenericDictionary(dictID, dictID, std::initializer_list<DictType>);

But there seems no reason it can’t have another:
template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
template<std::ranges::input_range R>
requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t, DictType>
GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::GenericDictionary(dictID, dictID, R&&);

And, in fact the first could simply delegate to the second.
The only code that would have to be changed in the constructor itself is the initialization of searchTable. In C++23 that could be:
searchTable{std::from_range, std::forward<R>(r)};

In C++20 and before it could be:
searchTable{std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r)}

Incidentally, there are a lot of weird, archaic C-isms peppered around the code, like typedef enum class x {/*...*/} x; instead of just enum class x {/*...*/};, the unnecessary struct in std::vector<struct TestPairs<GDPerformanceTestEnum16>>, and putting void in empty argument lists like int main(void). While most of them are technically legal C++, because they are archaic constructs, a modern compiler might very well warn about them.
Anywho, back to the code.
static std::string genEnumPreVal(std::size_t testSize)
{
    std::string tSize(std::to_string(testSize));
    std::string preEnumValue(enumName);
    return (preEnumValue += tSize);
}

This is rather verbose for what is ultimately just a one-liner:
auto genEnumPreVal(std::size_t testSize)
{
    return enumName + std::to_string(testSize);
}

I presume you were trying to avoid unnecessary allocations. But the thing is… the one-liner is not only equally as stingy with the allocations… starting in C++26 it’s even better.
Your code requires 3 allocations: one on each line. The one-liner, in C++20, also requires 2–3 allocations: the to_string() function does one, there may be another if enumName is a string view (if it’s a string, then, no, because unlike in your code, it is not copied), and finally the unnamed temporary string that gets returned. In C++23, strings can + directly with string views, so there are only two allocations (from to_string(), and then the temporary string that gets returned).
(Note that I am assuming no small-string optimization. In reality, the to_string() string will almost certainly require no allocation. Which means that in C++23, there is at maximum only a single allocation, in practice.)
On to genTestDataPairs().
    std::string tabPlusOpen;
    for (std::size_t tcount = 0; tcount < tabCount; ++tcount)
    {
        tabPlusOpen += "\t";
    }

There is a constructor for this:
    auto tabPlusOpen = std::string(tabCount, '\t');

In fact, the entire string construction could be:
    auto tabPlusOpen = std::string(tabCount, '\t') + '{';

And here:
    std::size_t lcount = MinEnumVal;
    for (; lcount < testSize ; ++lcount)
    {
        testOut << tabPlusOpen << enumValue << lcount << ", " << strValue <<
            lcount << "]},\n";
    }
    testOut << tabPlusOpen << enumValue << lcount << ", " << strValue <<
            lcount << "]}\n";

Again, be wary of the fact that MinEnumVal might not be 1. (Or if it absolutely will be, and never anything else, then maybe it should be a locally-defined constant.)
static bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), 
        s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

This could be much simpler, more flexible, and more efficient:
constexpr auto is_number(std::string_view s) noexcept
{
    auto const is_digit = [](unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); };

    return not s.empty() and std::ranges::all_of(s, is_digit);
}

But you need to be very cautious with std::isdigit()… no matter which flavour you use. This is a locale-aware function, so it could be behave erratically, and surprisingly.
If what you really want to check is that the character is literally 0 to 9 inclusive, then you should either explicitly use std::locale::classic(), or just manually spell out the digits:
constexpr auto is_number(std::string_view s) noexcept
{
    constexpr auto digits = std::array{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    constexpr auto is_digit = [&digits](char c) { return std::ranges::contains(digits, c); };

    return not s.empty() and std::ranges::all_of(s, is_digit);
}

And, of course, you could generalize that:
// Maybe needs a better name, and projections and predicate support.
template<
    std::ranges::input_range Needles,
    std::ranges::forward_range Haystack
>
constexpr auto all_of_are_in(Needles&& needs, Haystack&& haystack)
{
    return std::ranges::all_of(
        std::forward<Needles>(needles),
        [&haystack](auto&& needle) { return std::ranges::contains(haystack, needle); }
    );
}

constexpr auto is_number(std::string_view s) noexcept
{
    constexpr auto digits = std::array{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    return not s.empty() and std::ranges::all_of_are_in(s, digits);
}

But this function may be pointless, because…:
static std::size_t safeUserNumericInput(std::string message, std::size_t minValue, std::size_t maxValue)
{
    std::size_t safeNumber;

    std::string safeInput;
    bool hasNumber = false;

    do {
        std::cout << message << " [" << minValue << "," << maxValue << "]\n>>";
        std::cin >> safeInput;
        hasNumber = is_number(safeInput);
        if (hasNumber)
        {
            safeNumber = std::stoi(safeInput);
            hasNumber = (safeNumber >= minValue || safeNumber <= maxValue);
        }
    } while (!hasNumber);

    return safeNumber;
}

Okay, to start, there’s no reason this couldn’t be a template, used to scan in any kind of integer type:
template<std::integral Int>
auto input_number(std::string_view message, Int min, Int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw std::logic_error{"min is greater than max"};

    // ...
}

Now, it’s not a bad idea to put the string outside of the loop. I can’t imagine it will make a huge difference, but it does mean the string memory won’t have to be re-allocated each time.
What you do need to do, though, is check that the input stream is still good. Otherwise, if the user enters invalid data (or if some previous input had been invalid) or something else goes wrong, you’ll get stuck in an endless loop.
So:
template<std::integral Int>
auto input_number(std::string_view message, Int min, Int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw std::logic_error{"min is greater than max"};

    auto input = std::string{};
    while (std::in)
    {
        std::cout << message << " [" << min << "," << max << "]\n>>";

        if (std::cin >> input)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}

Okay, now in your current code, you first test if the string is a number… and then parse it as a number. That’s doing the work twice.
However… you are in locale-aware territory, which means… anything goes. I suspect you don’t want that. I suspect, judging by the fact that you tested the input string with isdigit(), that you really want to enforce the input of only ASCII decimal digits. No comma separators, no fancy Unicode digits or digits from other languages.
If that’s the case, then std::from_chars() is the tool you want:
template<std::integral Int>
auto input_number(std::string_view message, Int min, Int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw std::logic_error{"min is greater than max"};

    auto input = std::string{};
    while (std::in)
    {
        std::cout << message << " [" << min << "," << max << "]\n>>";

        if (std::cin >> input)
        {
            auto const first = input.data();
            auto const last = input.data() + input.size();

            auto v = Int{};
            auto const [input_end, ec] = from_chars(first, last, v);
            if (ec != std::errc{})
                continue;
            if (input_end != last) // for example: "123x"
                continue;

            if (v < min or v > max)
                continue;

            return v;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"cannot read from input"};
}

Something like that, though I would probably take a predicate to test whether the input value is valid, maybe only offering the min/max range as a simplification.
I’ll wrap up here, but I suggest that in general, you do the minimal amount of code generation you can get away with, and copy as much as possible verbatim (or include it).

Interesting, but a lot to take in. Thank you for the links to C++ Core Guidelines that is helpful. I started programming in C before there was C++ so there can definitely be problems there. If you look at my [first question on code review] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121917/reverse-polish-notation-calculator-similar-to-dc-on-unix-linux-systems-using-dyn) you will see that there was way too much C in my C++ code.

The one problem with putting anything in the test main.cpp is that the performance test cases will eventually be included in the unit testing in the parent directory which is not included in this question, it was in the previous question.

Minevalnum should be a constexpr. It is in a later version which hasn't been pushed to GitHub yet.

FYI, I tried to use std::format, but that is in g++-13 which is not supported on Ubuntu 22.04.

Just FYI, you missed 2 bugs in BasicGenericDictionaryTest.h. performanceExecution() was calling testIDtoNameLoop() twice and wasn't calling testIDtoNameLoop(). testIDtoNameLoop() had compilation errors. Both issues are fixed now. Still a very good review, and there are a couple of suggestions I'm still working on.

If you have the time you might want to look at the follow up question

Just a brief inspection of the main() function.
A small improvement that I find helpful when I generate files as part of a build - include indication of which program generated the file, in case it needs to be modified.
So here, I would get the program name from arguments, and (if successful) insert that into this message:

    testOut << "// Warning, this file is generated by a test generator\n";


Even better if we can include information about the inputs, to aid re-generating the file.

It might be desirable to produce the code on standard output stream, rather than creating/overwriting a fixed filename.  That makes the program both simpler and more flexible, and it makes development of the generator easier (e.g. comparing output of different versions).

We really should be testing the status of testOut after its close() (or of std::cout after its flush()) and updating our exit status accordingly, because if we didn't write everything we intended, we don't want to continue with dependent build steps.
